# What is "legendary" in Latin?

Tags: classical-latin, vocabulary, word-request, adjective

The English word "legendary" obviously comes from Latin, from the gerundive *legendus*, "that which is to be read".
(Less clumsy wording ideas are welcome!)
I might base a translation of the noun "legend" on this Latin word, but with "legendary" it feels awkward.
The obvious candidate, *legendarius*, does not seem to be classically attested and feels like a calque of the various adjectives like "legendary" in modern languages.

What would be a good classical Latin adjective to match the English "legendary"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good Latin word that matches "legend" pretty closely is *fabula*.
From that one can derive ***fabulosus***, which is widely attested in classical Latin.

It can mean something that appears in a fable (just as something legendary is literally something appearing in a legend), but also something great or incredible.
I think this captures the idea of "legendary" fairly well, and also matches in structure.

On a side note, *fabulosus* does not seem to match the modern English "fabulous" well.

The option *fabulosus* occurred to me some time after reading Tom Cotton's answer, and I thought I should record it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 7):

To the English, King Arthur is a legendary figure from fable, where the word is a synonym of 'mythical'. In the USA, Babe Ruth certainly was neither fable nor myth, but might easily be called a baseball legend. 'Fable' is in fact often used synonymously with legend, as are 'fabled' and 'fabulous with 'legendary'.

It depends on the meaning you actually have in mind. 'Legendary' is a weaselly, Humpty-Dumptyish kind  of word — it means whatever you choose it to mean — and in this case I don't think you will easily find a comparably flexible, single Latin equivalent. If praise is not intended, *commenticius* or *commentus*, 'imaginary' or 'invented' (from the verb *comminiscor*, to write fables or stories) is probably the nearest. With irony in mind, you might well think of words like 'apocryphal', 'romanticised'  and 'traditional' and select something to match these — maybe *translaticius* or *dubius*.

Comment: I think the implication of using Legendary on a real person is that "This is the sort of greatness you would only expect from a fictional story"

Comment: @corsiKa That is very well put!